# pass sed a long list of line numbers to remove from a file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to remove 500+ non-consecutive lines from a very large file with `sed`.

I have the lines stored in a `list.txt` file but I cant't use it in a `for` loop

```
for i in `cat list`; do  echo 'sed -i -e ' \'"$i"d\'' huge_file.txt' ; done
```

because line numbers in the original file would change every time `sed` removes one and exits.

I should do:

```
sed -i -e '1d;2d;93572277d;93572278d; ......;nth '  huge_file.txt
```

Is there a way to pass that list to `sed` in a file?

Comment: how are the numbers separated in your `list.txt` ?

Comment: just one per line, end of line is \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for a single particular task (not frequent) you may use the following GNU ***sed*** approach (assuming that numbers in `list.txt` are separated with newline `\n`):

```
sed -i "$(sed -z 's/\n/d;/g' list.txt)" huge_file.txt
```

Comment: Great, a long time has passed, still works great for me :)

Answer (score 3):

you can try with awk:

```
awk -v s="2,3,..,n" 'BEGIN{n=split(s,t,",");for(i=1;i<=n;i++)d[t[i]]=1}
                    !d[NR]' huge.txt
```

You pass the comma-separated line numbers to awk by `-v`, in awk split it in array, and check each line, if the line number in the array, skip.

Test it with small file, if it worked as you expected, you can do:

```
awk -v '....' '....' huge.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt huge.txt
```

to write the change back to your original input file.

### update

If you have 500 line numbers in another file, say, each number in a line, you can:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[FNR]' ln.txt huge.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this way i should still pass 500 line numbers on the command line and redirect output to another file ? that wolud double the disk usage of my system.

Comment: @ddfrenk you can pass shell variable to awk as well. sed (with -i) will have temp file as well. also you can save the 500 line number in file, let awk read it, it would be easier. see the update in answer.

Comment: ^1 Missed your *update* section. It should be on top! ;)

Comment: @ddfrenk with GNU awk you can use `gawk -i inplace '...'` to edit the file inplace.